# Embedding linklessly embeddable graphs without Borromean rings

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, topological-graph-theory, knot-link

A [*linklessly embeddable graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkless_embedding) is a graph which can be embedded into $\Bbb R^3$ so that no two of its cycles are linked. For example, the Petersen graph is not such a graph.

Now, I can think of another type of "linkedness" that is not already addressed by this notion, namely, whether an embedding contain a [*Borromean rings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings) configuration.
By that I mean three cycles of the graph, no two of which are linked, but all three can still not be "entangled into three separate cycles" (see the image from Wikipedia).

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

> **Question:** if a graph is linklessly embeddable, does it also have a linkless embedding *without a Borromean rings configuration*?
>
> Or the other way around, are there linklessly embeddable graphs that cannot be linklessly embedded without Borromean rings?

---

**Some thought**

Maybe one can show that whenever a graph cannot be embedded without Borromean rings, then the following two (black) paths must be present. This would then already imply the presence of a link:

[image]

This does not address the possibility that a graph might be linklessly embeddable, and embeddable without Borromean rings, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it that linklessly and flatly embeddable are the same family, and that a flat embedding can not contain a Borromean ring?

upd - clarification:
From the wiki article on linkless embeddings: "A flat embedding is an embedding with the property that every cycle is the boundary of a topological disk whose interior is disjoint from the graph." As far as I remember (and the wikipedia seems to confirm), every linklessly embeddable graph has a flat embedding (every flat embedding is trivially linkless). Finally, that a flat embedding can't contain a Borromean ring seems trivial to me from the above definition of a flat embedding (still can be wrong)

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by flatly embeddable and what it has to do with linkless embeddable and Borromean rings?

Comment: From the wiki article on linkless embeddings: "A flat embedding is an embedding with the property that every cycle is the boundary of a topological disk whose interior is disjoint from the graph." As far as I remember (and the wikipedia seems to confirm), every linklessly embeddable graph has a flat embedding (every flat embedding is trivially linkless). Finally, that a flat embedding can't contain a Borromean ring seems trivial to me from the above definition of a flat embedding (still can be wrong)

Comment: This is a helpful comment. And the claim seems to go back to the paper "Sachs' linkless embedding conjecture" by Robertson, Seymour and Thomas. They call it a "panelled embedding". If you could work your comment into your post to make it a full answer I would be happy to accept!